# Weird signs in my WP blog when I'm using &nbsp;

Tags: html, wordpress

recently I have strange bug i my WP blog, when I;m using `&nbsp;` - I'm getting weird signs like `?`.

this is image describing my problem: http://1drv.ms/1KIEoRc

Comment: could you please show the code or show the problem in a live site.

Comment: when i inspected your code in the address given above, it can be seen that there is no problem with the `&nbsp;` tags that you have used. Might be some other issue..check your code once more.

Comment: @Lal I edited this post and adding on top a lot of nbsp; and this "?" appear

Comment: sorry..didnt get you..

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your `head` section should solve the problem.